# Open new UserControl in the mainWindows

Tags: wpf

public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch ((sender as Button).Content.ToString())
        {
            case "UserControl 1":
                AddItemToContainer(new UserControl1());
                break;
            case "UserControl 2":
                AddItemToContainer(new UserControl2());
                break;
            case "UserControl 3":
                AddItemToContainer(new UserControl3());
                 break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void AddItemToContainer(UIElement _myElement)
    {
            Grid.SetColumn(_myElement, 1);
            HostContainer.Children.Add(_myElement);
    }
}
}
}
```

With this I can open a new userControl in myMainwindow

Let’s say something like adding child to myMainWinodw,Now I’m trying to click on a button from my userControl  so I open another userControl that take the place of the first one

I explain:

I have the mainWindows it has 3 button  first one to open the first UserControl the second one to open the second userControl and the third to open the last UserControl,imagine that I opened the first UserControl let’s call it UC1,

In the UC1 I have a button to open the second userControl (let’s call it UC2) I like that when I clik the button from the UC1 the UC2 is opened and take the place of the UC1 (of course the UC2 is still a child of myMainWinodw)
I have alredy try to call the AddItemToContainer methode from other methode but nothing is happened

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

This approach may help:

Call the container control and modify it's Children.This example assumes that the container control is a Grid.

C# Code for Window1

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HostContainer.Children.Add(new UserControl1(HostContainer));
    }
}
```

C# Code for UserControl1

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    Grid _hostContainer; 

    public UserControl1(Grid HostContainer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _hostContainer = HostContainer;
    }

    private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl2 UC2 = new UserControl2();
        _hostContainer.Children.Add(UC2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that helps but it does not realy take the place of the UC1 It just puch it a litel bit and take a litelle space of the mainWindow here is some snaps with explanation if you like http://startou.com/file/630-9411954b18.html